# Getting Ajax to execute using PHP generated values

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I'm completely new to AJAX, and am trying to use it to grab the details of sample users once said user is selected from a dropdown list generated via a php/mysql query. The process works fine when the dropdown values are hardcoded (`<option vlaue="1">1</option>, <option vlaue="2">2</option>, <option value="3">3</option>`, etc.), but nothing happens when I use the PHP version (snippet 2 below). I'm obviously missing out on some concept here, as I've Googled this every which way I can, as well as searched through Stackoverflow's archives, but can't find an answer. There's plenty on using AJAX to generate the list itself, but not on using it to grab PHP vars.

Any help/advice hugely appreciated.

The following code snips are:

1. The header javascript, forming the
   object
2. The form itself
3. The PHP action script

`function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","tester-engine.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}`

The form itself (db connection established):

```
<form>
    <select name="profile-owner" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                <?php
                        $contactresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts");

                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($contactresult)) 
                                        {
                                        echo '<option value="' . $row['ContactID'] . '">' . $row['ContactLastName'] . ', ' . $row['ContactFirstName'] . '</option>';
                                        }
    </form>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

And, finally, the proccessing script (tester-engine.php):

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('####', '####', '####');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("####", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE ContactID = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ContactFirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ContactLastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: AJAX is a client side script, therefore it is executed in the client's browser. PHP is server side and therefore all this code is executed before the HTTP response is sent to the client's browser. The source code the client receives is technically always 'hard-coded'.

Therefore this error to me suggests that your reference to ContactID is not actually a field in the contacts table. Is this the exact name of the field (case-sensitive)? Check your source to see if this value is actually set. I would suspect it contains no value.

Comment: If you could supply the table definition of contacts and a sample of the source code generated by your browser when viewing this page that would be useful to quickly find the cause of the problem.

Comment: The column name is "ContactID", tbl name is "contacts" - Here's the Scource code: `<html>

`<form>
<select name="profile-owner" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="1">Griffin, Peter</option><option value="2">Griffin, Lois</option><option value="3">Quagmire, Glen</option><option value="4">Swanson, Joseph</option> 
</form>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>`

Comment: Just to clarify, this does acually work when the form is simply written out in raw HTML. It's when I replace those options with PHP generated ones that things fall down. I figured maybe there was a sequence I was not aware of - generate form, capture values, then execute ajax, etc.... thx

Comment: This is quite confusing as your code in snippets 2 and 3 do not relate to the same column names: snippet 3 relates to the ID field as 'id' and contact names as 'FirstName' and 'LastName' whereas snippet 2 looks for fields called 'ContactId', 'ContactFirstName', 'ContactLastName'. I can't see any other problem myself, all I can advise is to triple check the field names as this inconsistency suggests you've overlooked something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer following comment feedback...

Snippet 2:

```
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($contactresult)) 
                                    {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $row['ContactID'] . '">' . $row['ContactLastName'] . ', ' . $row['ContactFirstName'] . '</option>';
                                    }
            ?>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

Snippet 3:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

// connection esablished

$sql="SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE ContactID = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
 <tr>
  <th>Firstname</th>
  <th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ContactFirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ContactLastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Your final page needs to look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  //alert(xmlhttp.readyState + " " + xmlhttp.status);

  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && (xmlhttp.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1))
    {
    //alert("receieved")
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://oldkitbag.com/kerrybog/modify-profile/tester-engine.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
//alert("sent")
}
</script>
<body>
<form>
    <select name="profile-owner" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                <option value="1">Griffin, Peter</option><option value="2">Griffin, Lois</option><option value="3">Quagmire, Glen</option><option value="4">Swanson, Joseph</option> 
    </select>
</form>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>





</body>
</html>
```

Copy and paste this code to test and then when you are happy the script works replace all the static HTML text within the form with PHP code and all will work fine... hopefully!!

Comment: No, my ID field in 'contact' IS called 'ContactID'. I changed the code anyway, just in case :), but it doesn't work and the value for each option becomes null (as it would as there is no 'id' field). Thx again tho!

Comment: How does tester-engine.php work then, as this page works by querying a field called 'id' not 'ContactID'? Please can you update your answer with a MySQL print out of your contacts table with a sample of data. Hopefully we can get to the bottom of this!

Comment: I cant post the print-out legibly (new user limitation on answering), so the comments fields are all I have I'm afraid. I've put it up here: http://oldkitbag.com/table-print-out.html

Comment: Sorry - just FYI, the tester-engine.php query does query the ContactID field, not 'id' - I had that changed but forgot to update. Ta for your patience!

Comment: Ok thanks, fields are as you said. Which leaves me to question the tester-engine.php script. Can you also test tester-engine.php directly from your browser with q=1? I see you have updated your tester-engine.php script to query using ContactID, so finally update the rows printed to 'ContactFirstName' and 'ContactLastName'... this should give you the results you desire!

Comment: GAAACK! Still not working - I thought you had it with the renaming of the fields (stupid of me to not see that, sorry again). How do I test directly with 'q=1'? Sounds like a useful technique...

Comment: I've updated the code above to reflect the exact layout as I'm using it now.

Comment: If I remove the PHP var for the ContactID in the form, and replace it with value="1", still doesn't work... :(

Comment: tester-engine.php is a webpage. So if you open a new browser window and type the url in as http://<website>/tester-engine.php?q=1. Then view the source to see if this is producing the expected outcome for contact 1.

Comment: Excellent - and that does return the correct response (Peter Griffin)!

Comment: Can you give me the url of the form page please, I'd like to have a look at it myself if that's ok.

Comment: Sure! http://oldkitbag.com/kerrybog/modify-profile/tester.php  (appreciate this!)

Comment: Thanks so much for sticking with it - is there any thing I can do for you? Add kudos or somesuch? :)

Comment: All good! What a small bug to have us running in circles. Glad you found the solution.